# How to slice particular values from a string using regular expression in JavaScript or Java

Tags: javascript, java

How do I slice, and get only string values excluding characters inside {} braces.

I'm able to get characters inside curly braces, but how to get contents outside the curly braces?

I have a string like this:

> name is {response.vital.name} and disease is {response.vital.some} and drug is {response.vital.dis}

I want output array like this:

> ["the name is","and disease is","and drug is"]

Comment: Upper cased, what should be upper cased + minor changes in description.

Comment: Instead of matching, [**split with the statements between brackets**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47715171/3669624).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Sub-Strings Outside Bracketed Sub-Strings:**

If you want all sub-strings outside of the curly braces then you can use the **String.split()** method with a simple Regular Expression:

```
String strg = "name is {response.vital.name} and disease is " + 
               "{response.vital.some} and drug is {response.vital.dis}";
String[] array = strg.split("\\{.*?\\}");
```

and to simply display the sub-strings within the array to console:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Console output will be:

```
[name is ,  and disease is ,  and drug is]
```

**Regular Expression Explanation:**

- **`\\`** matches the character `\` literally (case sensitive). We need to apply this escape character since all the brackets or braces we may want to work against are RegEx special characters and must be escaped in order to use them as literal characters. And, because the Regular Expression is a string we need to escape the escape character `\\` to make it legal. You can not place a single escape character into a Java String.
- **`{`** matches the character `{` literally (case sensitive).
- **`.*?`** matches any character (except for line terminators).
- **`*?`** ***Quantifier*** — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy).
- **`\\`** matches the character `\` literally (case sensitive). Again we need to escape the following close bracket.
- **`}`** matches the character `}` literally (case sensitive).

You could create a method to do this and accommodate any type of brace:

```
/**
 * Retrieves all sub-strings on either side of the supplied open brace and close brace. 
 * Everything within braces (including the braces) is excluded.<br>
 * 
 * @param inputString (String) The string to process. if Null or Null String is 
 * supplied then this method will throw a IllegalArgumentException exception.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param openBrace (String) The Open Brace of which to ignore content within. 
 * This can be Parentheses ( ( ), Square Brackets ( [ ), Curly Braces ( { ), or 
 * Chevron Brackets ( &lt; ). if Null or Null String is supplied then this method 
 * will throw a IllegalArgumentException exception.<br>
 * 
 * @param closeBrace (String) The Close Brace of which to ignore content within. 
 * This can be Parentheses ( ) ), Square Brackets ( ] ), Curly Braces ( } ), or 
 * Chevron Brackets ( &gt; ). if Null or Null String is supplied then this method 
 * will throw a IllegalArgumentException exception.<br>
 * 
 * @param trimElements (Optional - Boolean - Default is false) If this optional
 * parameter is set to boolean true then the returned array elements will have
 * any leading or trailing white-spaces removed.<br>
 * 
 * @return (Single Dimensional String Array) The detected sub-strings within a 
 * 1D String Array.
 */
public String[] getSubstringsOutsideBraces(String inputString, String openBrace, 
        String closeBrace, boolean... trimElements) {
    if (inputString == null || inputString.equals("") || 
        openBrace == null || openBrace.equals("") || 
        closeBrace == null || closeBrace.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\ngetSubstringsOutsideBraces() Method Error! "
                + "A method argument contains Null or Null String!\n");
    }
    boolean trim = false;
    if (trimElements.length > 0) { 
        trim = trimElements[0]; 
    }
    String[] array = inputString.split(
        // Using Ternary Operator so as to apply an additional 
        // RegEx to the split() method in order to remove the 
        // need for IF/ELSE and a FOR loop to trim elements if
        // desired to do so.
       (trim) ? "\\s*\\" + openBrace + ".*?\\" + closeBrace + 
             "\\s*" : "\\" + openBrace + ".*?\\" + closeBrace
    );
    return array;
}
```

And to use this method you might do it this way:

```
String strg = "name is {response.vital.name} and disease is "
                + "{response.vital.some} and drug is " 
                + "{response.vital.dis} More string content.";
String[] a = getSubstringsOutsideBraces(strg, "{", "}", true);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Console output will be:

```
[name is, and disease is, and drug is, More string content.]
```

> **Get Strings Inside Bracketed Sub-Strings:**

If what you are wanting to do is to collect the sub-string(s) or token(s) contained between Brackets or Braces within a string then a **Pattern/Matcher** approach works quite well for this task:

```
// Apply the Regular Expression to Pattern
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
// Run the pattern to see if there are any matches.
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(inputString);

// Establish a String List Object to hold any matches.
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

// Retrieve any matches found and add to List.        
while (matcher.find()) {
    list.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Regular Expression Explanation:**

Here is the explanation for the Regular Expression supplied to **Pattern**:

- **`\\`** matches the character `\` literally (case sensitive). We need to apply this escape character since all the brackets or braces we may want to work against are RegEx special characters and must be escaped in order to use them as literal characters. And, because the Regular Expression is a string we need to escape the escape character `\\` to make it legal. You can not place a single escape character into a Java String.
- **`{`** matches the character `{` literally (case sensitive).
- 1st Capturing **Group** (.*?) The Regular Expression indicates only 1 group.
- **`.*?`** matches any character (except for line terminators).
- **`*?`** ***Quantifier*** — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy).
- **`\\`** matches the character `\` literally (case sensitive). Again we need to escape the following close bracket.
- **`}`** matches the character `}` literally (case sensitive).

For ease of use, this concept can also be placed into and used as a method, for example:

```
/**
 * Retrieves all sub-strings inside of the supplied open brace and close brace. 
 * Everything outside of braces (including the braces) is excluded.<br>
 * 
 * @param inputString (String) The string to process. if Null or Null String is 
 * supplied then this method will throw a IllegalArgumentException exception.<br>
 * 
 * @param openBrace (String) The Open Brace of which to get content within. 
 * This can be Parentheses ( ( ), Square Brackets ( [ ), Curly Braces ( { ), or 
 * Chevron Brackets ( &lt; ). if Null or Null String is supplied then this method 
 * will throw a IllegalArgumentException exception.<br>
 * 
 * @param closeBrace (String) The Close Brace of which to get content within. 
 * This can be Parentheses ( ) ), Square Brackets ( ] ), Curly Braces ( } ), or 
 * Chevron Brackets ( &gt; ). if Null or Null String is supplied then this method 
 * will throw a IllegalArgumentException exception.<br>
 * 
 * @param trimElements (Optional - Boolean - Default is false) If this optional
 * parameter is set to boolean true then the returned array elements will have
 * any leading or trailing white-spaces removed.<br>
 * 
 * @return (Single Dimensional String Array) The detected sub-strings within a 
 * 1D String Array.
 */
public String[] getSubstringsInsideBraces(String inputString, String openBrace, 
        String closeBrace, boolean... trimElements) {
    // Make sure all arguments are supplied...
    if (inputString == null || inputString.equals("") || 
        openBrace == null || openBrace.equals("") || 
        closeBrace == null || closeBrace.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\ngetSubstringsInsideBraces() Method Error! "
                + "A method argument contains Null or Null String!\n");
    }
    // See if the option to trim bracketed content is desired.
    boolean trim = false;
    if (trimElements.length > 0) { 
        trim = trimElements[0]; 
    }

    // Apply the Regular Expression to Pattern. The supplied 
    // open and close braces are used within the expression.
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\" + openBrace + "(.*?)\\" + closeBrace);
    // Run the pattern to see if there are any matches.
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(inputString);
    // Establish a String List Object to hold any matches.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Retrieve any matches found and add to List.     
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Using a ternary operator against whether or not to 
        // Trim the matched item if desired before adding it 
        // to the List. This saves on doing a IF/THEN/ELSE.
        list.add((trim) ? matcher.group(1).trim() : matcher.group(1));
    }

    // Convert the List to a 1D String Array
    if (list.isEmpty()) { return null; }
    String[] array = new String[list.size()];
    array = list.toArray(array);

    // Return the 1D String Array
    return array;
}
```

To use the above method:

```
String strg = "name is {response.vital.name} and disease is "
                    + "{response.vital.some  } and drug is "
                    + "{response.vital.dis } More string content.";
String[] a = getSubstringsInsideBraces(strg, "{", "}", true);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

The console output will be:

```
[response.vital.name, response.vital.some, response.vital.dis]
```

If you want the above method to return a **List** object (which is what it fills to start with) then simply remove the conversion code within the method, instead of `return array;` use `return list;`, and declare your method to return a `List<String>` instead of `String[]`. Of course change the text within the JavaDoc above the method to reflect this change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching content inside brackets you can just split by content between brackets.

In JavaScript you can use **[`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** function with this regex **[`/{\[\w\.\]+}/i`](https://regex101.com/r/aYOkA4/1)**:

```
var str = 'name is {response.vital.name} and disease is {response.vital.some} and drug is {response.vital.dis}';
var arr = str.split(/{[\w\.]+}/).filter(s => s != "");
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = 'name is {response.vital.name} and disease is {response.vital.some} and drug is {response.vital.dis}';
var arr = str.split(/{[\w\.]+}/).filter(s => s != "");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: For your regex the flag `i` is needless, and `g` for `split` regex is needless, too.

Comment: Don't forget the `i`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can do the following:

```
s = "name is {response.vital.name} and disease is {response.vital.some} and drug is {response.vital.dis}";
a = s.split(/\s*\{[^\}]*\}\s*/)
```

The Java solution looks quite similar:

```
String s = "name is {response.vital.name} and disease is {response.vital.some} and drug is {response.vital.dis}";
String[] a = s.split("\\s*\\{[^\\}]*\\}\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in JS:

```js
var str = "name is {response.vital.name} and disease is {response.vital.some} and drug is {response.vital.dis}";
var res = str.split('{').reduce((m, o) => {
    if (o.indexOf('}') > -1 && o.split('}')[1]) {
        m.push(o.split('}')[1].trim());
    } else {
        m.push(o.trim());
    }
    return m;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```